# Access Pyspark dataframe's (n+1)th column when nth column value is 'x'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 1 million rows and 200 columns. I have to put only a few columns in my final dataframe. If for every row one of the column value is 3300, i  need to put the next column's value in my dataframe.

For eg:

[image]

Here i have col3 value as 3300 so i need to put col4 in  my final dataframe. Using column name won't be a good solution because i have 200 columns.

Comment: How about if there is no column with that value on a row? If the last column has that value so there is no next? If multiple columns have the value?

Comment: If there is a row with no column value=3300, then it shouldn't be added in the final dataframe. The cases of multiple columns having same value is not possible and the last column can not be 3300. The schema of the table is in this way: code_n followed by value_n. We have to check for code if it is equal to 3300 and then give the output.

Comment: What is your expected output one column with the column name that you want or value of that column

Comment: Value of that column

Comment: Check the answer I included both als o I considered all cases with only first match.

Comment: @AmanKumarSingh, please never add images in the question rather paste the sample input and output

Comment: Ok @SomeshwarKale will take care of that

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1100,1200,3300,4400,5500),(3300,1200,3200,4400,5500),(1100,1200,3200,4400,3300),(1100,3300,3300,4400,5500)],['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])

+----+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|1100|1200|3300|4400|5500|
|3300|1200|3200|4400|5500|
|1100|1200|3200|4400|3300|
|1100|3300|3300|4400|5500|
+----+----+----+----+----+

from itertools import chain
column_map = create_map([lit(i) for i in chain(*enumerate(df.columns))])

df.withColumn('data',array(df.columns)).\
   withColumn('index',array_position(array(df.columns),3300)).\
   withColumn('value',col('data').getItem(col('index'))).\
   withColumn('columnName',column_map[col('index')]).\
   select('columnName','value').show()

+----------+-----+
|columnName|value|
+----------+-----+
|      col4| 4400|
|      col2| 1200|
|      null| null|
|      col3| 3300|
+----------+-----+
```

**Update**
To fetch fixed cols and the value of column right after 3300 use this

```
df.withColumn('data',array(df.columns)).\
   withColumn('index',array_position(array(df.columns),3300)).\
   withColumn('value',col('data').getItem(col('index'))).\
   withColumn('columnName',column_map[col('index')]).\
   select('col1','col2','value')
```

Comment: How will the code change if i want to have col1, col2 and the required column in my final dataframe for all rows?

Comment: You can't have distinct columns for each row instead you can have something like fixed columns then the fetched value `col1,col2,value` where value will contain the column value next to 3300...Check the update in answer

Comment: I am not able to use array as my dataframe consists of data of different datatype. What can be done?

Comment: Can't we use index in place of array to accommodate?